# Manually Disable and enable Android HostApduService?

Tags: java, android, nfc

Hi i have created a class that extends HostApduService and there is a scenario where i want to stop or pause the service awaiting some input from the user before resuming the service again. Is this possible?

i could not find any API that manually stops/pauses the HostApduService.

snippet of my HostApduService on what i want it to do

```
protected byte[] processApdu(byte[] apdu) {
    if(isEnabled){
          /proccess apdu as normal
  }
}
```

snippet of some action in android on a ui

```
new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //disable/pause hostapdu service???
            }
        });

new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //enable/resume hostapdu service???
                }
            });
```

processApdu always needs to return some bytes to the terminal but i dont want it to and want to disablle/pause it until further notice

Answer (score 4):

To disable:

```
context.getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(context, MyHostApduService.class), PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP)
```

To enable:

```
context.getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(new ComponentName(context, MyHostApduService.class), PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP)
```

You could also try saving the enabled/disabled state in Shared Preferences